# Smarty 3 and spl_autoload_register

Tags: php, smarty, autoload

I know I need to use spl_autoload_register with Smarty 3. I am registering my autoload function after smarty initializes. But smarty is trying to use my own autoload function instead of the smartyAutoload defined function. Causing an error because it obviously cant find the smarty files using my autoload. Here is the code with everything else cut out to show how it is layed out currently.

I'm sure it is just an order placement issue or something.

```
<?php
class application {

    // include smarty
    require_once(SMARTY_DIR.'Smarty.class.php');

    // init controller class which initializes smarty
    $controller = new Controller();
}

function autoLoader($class) {

    // determine what type class it is and call from that directory
    $dir = strtolower(strstr($class, '_', true));
    $name = substr( strtolower( strstr($class, '_') ), 1 );

    switch($dir) {

        case 'component':

            break;

        default:
            require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.$name.'.class.php');
            break;

    }
}

spl_autoload_register("autoLoader");

?>
```

Comment: Might be a smarty bug? I came across the same issue, but actually found that the Smarty autoloader was fine.  It just wasn't finding the class it was looking for, and so passed the call on to my autoloader instead.  My autoloader raises an error when the file is not found, but the Smarty one doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make your autoloader compatbile (that's what `spl_autoload_register` is actually for) by *only* require a file if it's one of *your* classes.

You can do this by checking the class name against a namespace or a whitelist or with `is_file` (store the whitelist in the file-system):

```
    default:
        $path = LIB_PATH.DS.$name.'.class.php';
        if (is_file($path)) require_once($path);
        break;
```

Comment: Ah yes, not even sure why I didnt think of that. But I'm still curious of the underlying issue. Because I thought the functions were called in their registered order. Since smartys was first, shouldnt it call smartyAutoload first avoiding the error I am getting?

Comment: I don't specifically know about the order, but `require` will do a fatal error if the file does not exists/can't be included and stops then. Did this solve your issue btw?

Comment: I just notced that even though I am calling spl_autoload_register after my smarty intialization, it is still showing up as the first autoload function when i call spl_autload_functions(). Not sure what is causing this.

Comment: @JustinCarlson: [According to the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php), the callbacks are called in the order they are registered. You can get the stack via [`spl_autoload_functions`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-functions.php)

Comment: @JustinCarlson: Functions can be registered, removed and then add again to the stack. That could be at least an explanation, but it's an assumption only if that happens with smarty autoloader.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's relevant to you, but I tracked my problem down to a file called `smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php`, function `callTagCompiler()`.

My code (inside a *.tpl file) calls a smarty plugin function.  My plugin-function is called `Load_PO`, meaning that the Smarty engine then searches for a class named `Smarty_Internal_Compile_Load_PO`.

Of course, neither the Smarty auto-loader, nor my custom auto-loader finds this template.  The problem, in fact, was that my auto-loader errors when a file is not found.

The problem can be resolved in 2 ways:

1. Change my auto-loader to ignore searches `if (substr($class_name,0,24) = 'Smarty_Internal_Compile_')`
2. Modify file `smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php`, and change function `callTagCompiler()` as shown below

Change the code

```
class_exists ($class_name)
```

To

```
class_exists ($class_name, false)
```